# Contiki: Get Global addresses from Local link addresses

Tags: contiki

In the file `rpl-icmp6.c`, in the method `dio_input`, the `from` variable is a local link address. I want to find the routes from the node who sent that DIO, using `uip_ds6_route_lookup(&from)`. However, inside this method, they compare ip-addresses using `uip_ipaddr_prefixcmp` instead of `uip_ipaddr_cmp`. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a method in contiki that translate link-local addresses to prefix - global addresses of neighbor nodes?

EDIT:

```
uip_ipaddr_t from;
uip_ipaddr_copy(&from, &UIP_IP_BUF->srcipaddr);
route = uip_ds6_route_lookup(from);
  if(route != NULL) {
    const uip_ipaddr_t *nexthop = uip_ds6_route_nexthop(route);
    if(uip_ipaddr_cmp(&from, &nexthop)) {
       /* Test rank of the node */
       return 1;
}
```

This is the code, and the method `uip_ds6_route_lookup` can not find any route because the ipaddress is local link.

Comment: where's the rpl-icmp.c code?

Comment: `/home/user/contiki/core/net/rpl/rpl-icmp6.c`

Comment: can you paste code?

Comment: Use `memcpy` or a `for` loop to change the prefix of the address. There is no specific method for this.